# Clickable table row using Rails/jQuery - can't get link within row working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm playing around with a Rails 4 project and I was successfully able to make it so clicking anywhere in the table row would link to the show page for an item (using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Make table rows clickable
  $(".table tr").click(function() {
    var href = $(this).find("a").first().attr("href");
    if(href) {
      window.location.href = href;
    }
  });
  // Stops links from triggering the tr click???
  $("a").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

The second part with `event.stopPropagation()` needs to be included to stop links within the row from also triggering the table row click, since they exist inside it as child elements, as seen here (the first two links just go to the show page for the item which is what the row click uses): https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VmSF.jpg

The problem is, it works for the "Edit" link (and prevents triggering an additional redirect for the first two links), but not the "Destroy" link - clicking it will just act like I'm clicking anywhere else in the row and send me to the show page for the item. Here is relevant HTML output for those two buttons:

```
<tr>
  ...
  <td><a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="/foods/2603/edit">Edit</a></td>
  <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/foods/2603" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a></td>
</tr>
```

Now I know Rails has its own Javascript functions to pop up the confirmation box and send the `DELETE` request which I guess is why it has those `data-confirm` and `data-method` attributes; my guess is that this has something to do with why my own js code isn't working. Can anybody help me out here?

Note that if I exclude `event.stopPropagation()` then the confirmation box will appear very briefly before I'm redirected, but as it stands no box pops up at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more searching I eventually came across [this Github issue](http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/252) which seems to be the one I've run up against. Apparently the underlying issue is unsolvable because of the way Rails (specifically jquery-ujs) works, but there was a workaround provided which I was able to adapt to my case after a bit of playing around:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Make table rows clickable
  $(".table tr").on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is(":not(a)")) {
      var href = $(this).find("a").first().attr("href");
      if(href) {
        window.location.href = href;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Basically now if I click the table row it'll first check to see that the element that's being clicked is not an `a` element (i.e. is not already a link) and only then send the user to the item page. If it is a link, the Javascript stops and the link has its normal behaviour. Seems to work fine.

One last quick question though, is `if (target.is(":not(a)"))` the best or most optimized way to express that condition?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in
`$('.table tr').click(function(){...})`

My guess is that the tables are dynamically loaded, so you should use either;
`$('.table tr').on('click', function(){...})` or
`$('.table tr').live('click', function(){...})`

Or maybe try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ez6f/7/)

To make things interesting,

```
$('.table tr').on('click', 'a', function(){
    var data = $(this).attr('custom-attr')

    if(data == 'something'){
        //Do something
    }
})
```

Comment: No difference using `.on`. Had a look at the jsfiddle and tried the same syntax but it made no difference either.

`.live` simply broke the functionality, so the buttons worked properly but clicking the row didn't.